iptables - Slow or Missing Traffic
im having an issue with iptables configuration on my server. I've set an ACCEPT rule for port 80 to allow HTTP traffic, but despite this, websites are loading very slowly or not at all.
Could someone please help me identify possible causes for this issue? Are there other factors that could be affecting HTTP traffic slowdown despite having an ACCEPT rule for port 80?
I set an ACCEPT rule for port 80 to allow HTTP traffic :
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT 
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT

I checked the status of iptables rules using the command: sudo iptables -L -v
Despite these rules, websites are loading very slowly or not at all. I expected that setting the ACCEPT rule for port 80 would enable normal loading of websites. Are there other factors that could be affecting HTTP traffic slowdown despite having this rule in place? Are there additional steps I can take to improve my iptables configuration and ensure proper functioning of the web services?
Thank you

Can this help you ?

Please add output of iptables-save to your question, so we can see the full firewall setup.
